# PHP header redirect in jQuery Mobile

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, header, redirecttoaction

I'm working on a jquery mobile web app and do a sessioncheck with php on pages I need the user to be logged-in. If not, the user will be redirected to the login.php?r=L29yZGVyLnBocD9kZWFsX2lkPTEwMDM2MjM= (base64_encode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) to login. After the login he has to be redirected to the page he actually requested.

Unfortunately JQM doesn't update the URL, so i can't grab the GET parameter ?r=.... as it is not there. Just a page reload (F5) updates the url.

Here the sessioncheck code which does the redirect if user is not logged-in:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["member"]) || (isset($_SESSION["member"]) && (int)$_SESSION["member"]["member_id"]==0)){
unset($_SESSION["member"]); 
Header("Location: " . SITE_ROOT . "/login.php?r=".base64_encode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
exit;
```

}

What do you guys suggest to tell jQuery mobile that the target has changed.
Of course my redirect happens before the DOCTYPE tag

Cheers

Comment: When are you wanting to redirect? If they try to view the page and are not logged in? Or after they log in?

Comment: Hi Adam, they click the link to a page which needs the user logged in. On this page there is the sessioncheck waiting to redirect to login.php&r=..... in case he is not already logged-in(session)

Comment: Can you clarify: you call the back-end pages through AJAX, and want to handle a "please redirect" in a response to the AJAX call?

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify a `data-url` attribute into the page div?

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="/login" id="login-page">
```